# Drive Outlook Through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to create a meeting invite only to book a room in outlook through Excel.

this is the code I am using,

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myApt = myOutlook.CreateItem(1)
myApt.Subject = "Training"
myApt.Start = Now
myApt.RequiredAttendees = "B 101-Training Room-24 <B101-TrainingRoom-24.IOC@cummins.com>"
myApt.End = Now + 30
myApt.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
myApt.send
MsgBox ("Meeting Invite Sent")
Set myOutlook = Nothing
Set myApt = Nothing
End Sub
```

this code doesnot create any meeting invite, but doesnot give error as well.
Can please tell what could be the missing thing?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI that appt is 30 days long (`Now + 30` is days) - `olMeeting` will be undefined (0) as your late binding, try adding `.display` before `.send` to see the appt

Comment: what should I add for .display?

Comment: myApt.display = True    ?

Comment: Did you try to make exactly the same meeting manualy ?
Your code work for me (with another email).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use recipients, trying this

myApt.Recipients.Add("B 101-Training Room-24 <B101-TrainingRoom-24.IOC@cummins.com>")

Comment: it still doesnot create a meeting invite.. and the only problem is that it is not adding attendees

Answer (score 0):

The [RequiredAttendees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff867639.aspx) property only contains the display names for the required attendees. The attendee list should be set by using the [Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff866751.aspx) collection.

Comment: yup.. I did try that.. but no luck.. it still doesnot add invitees

Comment: Where do you expect invites added?

Answer (score 0):

Resources are usually added as BCC recipients:

```
set recip = myApt.RequiredAttendees("B 101-Training Room-24 <B101-TrainingRoom-24.IOC@cummins.com>")
recip.Type = 3 'olBCC
recip.Resolve
```

Do you see the meeting request in the Sent Items folder?

Answer (score 0):

the code given adds all the fields except attendees. I want to have 'Invite attendees' option coded.

```
Set recip = myApt.RequiredAttendees("B 101-Training Room-24 <B101-TrainingRoom-24.IOC@cummins.com>")
```

is there any other way to add the invitees? FYI, I am using Outlook 2013.